# How to select top 10% of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it's possible to select the maximum value in SQL with MAX(), but if I have a table with two columns, an ID and a value, is it possible to select the top 10% of values for each ID. There is not a set number of values for each ID.

EDIT: Apologies for not being clearer,
I'm working with Microsoft SQL server Managment studio. Table A looks like:

```
ID,     Value
112345, 1
112345, 2
112345, 3
112345, 2
112345, 3
112345, 18
112345, 32
112357, 10
112346, 15
112346, 16
```

If it were to select the top 50% for each I would want the select to produce:

```
ID,     Value
112345, 3
112345, 3
112345, 18
112345, 32
112357, 10
112346, 16
```

I would prefer if the number of returned rows was rounded up, eg. 10% of an ID that had 4 rows would still return 1 value

Comment: top 10 % based on what? can you post some sample data and expected output? also, which database are you using? sql is just a standard

Comment: Are you asking about the top 10% by `value` or the top 10% of the total number of records?

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Specifically of 10,11,12,100,1000 do you want 100, 1000 or just 1000?

Comment: please also add rdbms-hint. which one do you use?

Comment: please provide sample data with desired output

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I've edited the main question, I hope this helps. 
The top 10% by value @Siyual

Comment: in your example output it is 50% of the number of rows, not 50% by value. Its just ORDERED by value...

Comment: @swe his sample output is the top 50% highest values per ID (top 4 highest values of the 7 records with ID 112345, top 1 highest value from the 2 records with ID 112346...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the first 10% of rows ordered by Value (desc), you can achieve that by using window functions:

```
select * from (
select ID, Value, COUNT(*) over (partition by ID) as countrows, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Value desc) as rowno from mytable) as innertab
where rowno <= floor(countrows*0.1+0.9)
order by ID, rowno
```

The floor-thing brings 1 row per 1-10 rows, 2 rows for 11-20 rows and so on.

Comment: At the end you order by parentid, but that's not defined in your answer. Would this just be ID?

Comment: @JoshuaKidd sry, i tested with my table, where there was a parentid, and after that, i changed to names and forgot that. i corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use CROSS APPLY and specify TOP n PERCENT

```
SELECT x.*
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM tab ) a
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT ID, Value FROM tab b WHERE b.ID = a.ID) x
```

TOP n PERCENT will produce at least one row.